# React Router v6 Error: Failed prop type: The prop `location` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a very basic setup, trying out react router v6. But I always get the errormessage mentioned in the headline, when I click on the "go home" button. How can I fix this?

App.js

```
render({AppRoutes})
```

AppRoutes.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';
import DefaultComponent from './scenes/Default/Default2';
import TestComponent from './scenes/Default/TestComponent';

const AppRoutes = (
<HashRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element = {<DefaultComponent/>}>
      <Route path="test" element={<TestComponent/>}/>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</HashRouter>
);
export default AppRoutes;
```

DefaultComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function DefaultComponent() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  function handleClick() {
    navigate('/test');
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>go home</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default DefaultComponent;
```

TestComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';

function TestComponent (){
  return (
    <h1>This is a test!</h1>
  );
}
export default TestComponent;
```

Comment: Why not using the <Link> component provided by React-router ?

Comment: Whats the difference? I think I did a very basic example here, which should work with the suggested hooks. I want to navigate the user programmatically, like here in an eventHandler.